# How do I show all events firing in a web page without using a plugin/extension?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I know that using Firebug or other inspectors will show you all events firing, but is there any way to do this from in-page JavaScript (especially if you don't know the event name that you're looking for?)

This is my use case: the new Galaxy S4 has "air gestures" - when you gesture in front of the web page, it will scroll up and down. I'm trying to find out whether these generate events detectable by content or are they swallowed by the OS.

Comment: Are you trying to watch every event dispatched (there may be quite a few every second, such as mousemove, keyup/down/press), or just looking for listeners being called?

Comment: `function(e) { var eventname=e.type; /*is your friend!*/ }`

Comment: you want something like this? http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables/demo_events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already know that JS event handlers can for example choose to [stop the immediate propagation of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopImmediatePropagation) so that no other handlers get called for the event in question.

This means that in order to do what you propose, you 'd have to attach handlers for *all* events on *all* elements *and* those handlers would have to be first in each and every case so that your handler gets called before anyone else has a chance to stop that from happening. It goes without saying that you 'd also have to know the event names.

So no, you can't really do that.